# How to get number of floats in file?

Tags: c, file, floating-point, numbers, lines

I have a file with float numbers, here is an example:

```
0.01
0.24
0.08
0.15
0.7
0.22
0.05
0.28
0.4
0.44
0.8
0.55
```

Now I need to get number of all floats (in this case 12). Empty lines should be avoided.

I did this:

```
  FILE *f, *junk;
  if (MYTHREAD == 0) {
    f = fopen ("dane.dat", "r");    
    junk = fopen ("/dev/null", "w");    

    for(size = 0; fscanf(f, "%f\n", junk) != EOF; ++size);

    fclose(junk);
    fclose(f);
  }
```

and it returns me 128 O_o. What is wrong?

Comment: a) Your code doesn't return anything? b) The parameters for fscanf are wrong. You should provide a pointer to store the read float in memory rather than a file pointer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't check if `fscanf` did read a float. Use the fact that it return the number of item it read.

Also, don't read to `FILE*`. read to `float*`.

This code should work:

```
float o;
int i,size=0;
while ((i=fscanf(f,"%f",&o))!=EOF) size+=i;
```